# Acquire value for every change in JSlider

Tags: java, swing, jslider

I am trying to get the value of the `JSlider` for every time I change the slider position. I decided to test it by print it first.

```
package training;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;   
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class Temperature extends JSlider {

    JSlider Temp = new JSlider(-50, 50, 0);

    public Temperature (){
        add(Temp);
        Temp.setMajorTickSpacing(10);
        Temp.setMinorTickSpacing(1);

        Temp.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener () {
             public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent evt) {
            JSlider Temp = (JSlider) evt.getSource();
            if (!Temp.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
            int value = Temp.getValue();
            System.out.println(value);
                    }
                  }
            });
    }
}
```

And then I call the method in the main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Temperature ns = new Temperature();
        System.out.println("User dir: " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Window");
        JPanel p = new Training();

        ns.add(new Temperature());

           f.setSize(1100, 600);
           p.setSize(750, 600); 
           f.add(p);
           f.add(ns, BorderLayout.EAST);
           f.setVisible(true);

}
```

But the console didn't print any value when I change the slider position.
Any idea of where the flaw of my code is?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 3) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 4) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  ..

Comment: .. The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!

Comment: You're adding a `JSlider` to a `JSlider` - suspicion - you're not listening to the right slider

Comment: @MadProgrammer I''ve deleted the `add(Temp);` and the console still doesn't print anything.

Comment: @Conan You're still listening to a `JSlider` which is NOT on the screen.  Drop the `Temperature` class altogether, it's just confusing. Create and configure an instance of `JSlider` manually and retest

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you very much. It works now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, change:

```
public class Temperature extends JSlider {

    JSlider Temp = new JSlider(-50, 50, 0);
```

To:

```
public class Temperature { // NO NEED TO EXTEND HERE!

    JSlider Temp = new JSlider(-50, 50, 0);
```

..then provide a method to return the slider that actually has a change listener attached.

Comment: Might want to extend from a component ... but I'd just create a factory method to return a `JSlider` configured as required

Comment: @MadProgrammer *"Might want to extend from a component ..."* Want is not the same as need. I have no interest in what a coder 'wants'. ;) *"but I'd just create a factory method"* Good point. There is really no .. need (**D'Oh!**) for a separate class for this.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson Delete the `extends JSlider` then i can't access the `Temperature ()` in the main class.

Comment: Did you read all the way to the end of the short answer, or did your attention span fail you?

Comment: @AndrewThompson My sincere apology. I'm new to java and I just don't know the "What came after A letter" in java. Guess I need help on "provide a method to return the slider that actually has a change listener attached." you said earlier. And English is not my first language too.

Comment: *"Guess I need help on "provide a method to return the slider that actually has a change listener attached.""* So .. what don't you understand? I don't intend explaining every word (especially not since it means adding more words you might not understand) & SO is not the place for tutorials on methods (which you should be familiar with long before trying to make apps with a GUI).

Comment: I Tried to drop the `Temperature` class as the @MadProgrammer advised and it works. Thank you for the help and I will try to learn more about the basics before asking here, @Andrew Thompson

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track...
My best advice, is to listen.

Listen for the changes.

When you listen for them, if your "hearing", is good.. 
Then you should be able to, at the least, interpret what the change is, in what you are continuously listening to.

The changeListener is where you are able to hear the changes in what you are listening to. It is similar to an action listener, for a Jbutton.

If a button is clicked, you "Listen" for the click. Once the click is dispatched, it is "heard", and then in which, the abstract method you specified, becomes executed.